# Running Total Conditional Summing with Stops Array Formula

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Attached is a [Test Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cGyKRKv45FNoTBMcPrHjOhSCsfBwG374NfdzdRO0oCQ/edit?usp=sharing) which shows results and expected results. Also, there is a screen shot below, which by picture, should explain what is wanted for those who have trouble reading.

The goal is to have a running total of streaks. Such a total should come to an end whenever the streak ends.

This formula works but requires user intervention through dragging:

```
=if(B3="start",0,if(B2="start",2,C2+1))
```

When wrapped as an array formula, a circular dependency error arises because of the else clause of the second if(), the `C2+1` bit.

Here is a screenshot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xovsS.png][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xovsS.png)

Comment: For both? What? The solution would be one array formula.

Comment: Oh. Google Sheets, if you can, thanks.

Comment: Related: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/2afFa_GbhDY

Answer (score 0):

Does this work in cell D1?

```
=arrayformula(IF(ROW(D1)=1,"Wanted Array Forumla to Fill in the 
 Gaps",IF(ISNUMBER(A2:A),if(B2:B="start",0,if(B1:B="start",2,)))))
```

Comment: Alas, no. I think I shall rework the problem all the same. Since I can get a column of `x ∈ {-1,1}`, all I will need is a formula to tally a streak of -1 or 1 and when the streak ends, put the count on the same row as the last number for a streak. In this way, I can still match up streak counts to dates. What we're trying to do is map counts of streaks to their corresponding end dates.